# No sync for Chrome when launched from Windows 8 tile

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8

I just installed Windows 8 Enterprise.

- I installed Google Chrome and launched it from the Windows desktop.
- I activated the Chrome sync which required me to assign a new application-specific password (since I use Google's 2-step authentication).
- Now when I launch Chrome from the Windows desktop I correctly see all my toolbars, plugins and bookmarks.

However, when I launch Chrome from the tile on the Metro screen, Chrome starts but it is NOT synced. In the top right corner of the apps screen, I see *'Not signed in to Chrome (You're missing out -- sign in)'*.  If I try to sign in it requires a new application-specific password. It's as if Chrome is using a different profile depending on whether I launch it from Metro or the Windows desktop. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's as if Chrome is using a different profile depending

That's what it is, Chrome launched from Windows 8 tile starts in <s>Metro</s> Modern UI mode, while that launched from Desktop starts it in Desktop mode.

The profile folders for each mode is separate, with the <s>Metro</s> Modern UI mode storing it's profile in Metro folder under `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Metro`

**However**, it looks like this is going away soon(M23+), [per this bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=151099):

> We're still warning users about their data being separate in Metro and
>   desktop, which isn't true anymore in M23+.

Comment: Yes Chrome 23 has fixed the problem.